# Perl on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c++, c, perl, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to know if there is already a Windows Phone 8 port or implementation of Perl or something else that would allow me to run a Perl application on Windows Phone 8? If you know of something like this for Windows RT it should probably also work here. I know this can be done for Python: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/515115/compiling-python-for-windows-phone-8 or I think through IronPython.

Also how practical would it be to port the C based Python to Windows Phone 8 which does indeed support native code.

Comment: strange wish, but I want to know this too.

Comment: Yeah, I need to run a perl applcation and porting to c# or c++ it is just completely unpractical